# Using &&'s short-circuiting as an if statement?

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

I saw this line in the `jQuery.form.js` source code:

```
g && $.event.trigger("ajaxComplete", [xhr, s]);
```

My first thought was wtf??

My next thought was, I can't decide if that's ugly or elegant.

I'm not a Javascript guru by any means so my question is 2-fold.  First I want to confirm I understand it properly.  Is the above line equivalent to:

```
if (g) {
    $.event.trigger("ajaxComplete", [xhr, s]);
}
```

And secondly is this common / accepted practice in Javascript?  On the one hand it's succinct, but on the other it can be a bit cryptic if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: Considering that those braces aren't even required in the second case, I'd vote unclear and ugly, although I am not a JavaScript guru either.

Comment: Related [Does JavaScript have short-circuit evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation)

Comment: For details (especially how it works with truthy/falsy objects), consider  [these examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#examples)!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, your two examples are equivalent. It works like this in pretty much all languages, but it's become rather idiomatic in Javascript. Personally I think it's good in some situations but can be abused in others. It's definitely shorter though, which can be important to minimize Javascript load times.

Also see [Can somebody explain how John Resig's pretty.js JavaScript works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024974/can-somebody-explain-how-john-resigs-pretty-js-javascript-works/)

Comment: There's no short circuiting in VBA, which I learned the hard way after 4 hours of debugging.

Comment: I've tried to shortcircuit like this with java and it seems the language doesn't allow it. Am I correct?

Comment: @DarylBennett there is---"AndAlso" and "OrElse". I'd say kill me now, but having no pulse is already a prerequisite for programming VB.

Comment: @MaxG Java definitely has short-circuiting of boolean operators, it just doesn't let you use them as a statement.

Answer (score 10):

It's standard, but neither [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) nor [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) like it:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Answer (score 6):

You must be careful because this short-circuiting can be bypassed if there is an `||` in the conditional:

```
false && true || true
> true
```

To avoid this, be sure to group the conditionals:

```
false && (true || true)
> false
```

Comment: That's because ANDs take precedence on ORs when they're side-by-side. Equivalent maths situation would be `2*3+2 = 8` when `2*(3+2) = 10`. This is way too easy to miss...

Comment: Be explicit rather than claver and use an if statement...your brain will thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's equivalent to an `if` as you wrote. It's certainly not an uncommon practice. Whether it's accepted depends on who is (or isn't) doing the accepting...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you understand it (in that context); yes, it is standard practice in JavaScript.

Comment: It most certainly is not standard practice in C#.  In fact it won't even compile "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: And that's only if the 2nd half returns `bool` otherwise you get "&& operator cannot be applied to arguments of type 'bool' and '[whatever type the 2nd half returns]`"

Comment: you need to put it in brackets and assign. Just for you, I'll remove the bit about C# because the question is specifically about JavaScript.

Comment: Chap the whole point is that shortcircuiting is to replace if statements - What exactly can an if return other than bool?

Comment: The question wasn't about how short-circuiting works though.  It's specifically about using a short-circuited boolean operator for the side-effects and not for boolean logic.  There is no assignment happening in the sample I gave above.

Comment: @Carno an `if` statement doesn't return anything.  It controls the flow of execution.

Comment: Assignment is not occuring but an evaluation of g is happening.

Comment: if performs an evalutation upon a condition and RETURNS, ahem, a bool

Comment: @Carno I don't disagree that an evaluation of g is happening, but that isn't the question.  I'm mostly contesting the earlier statement about C# but maybe I should just drop it since you removed it from your answer.  Basically if my example were instead `someBool && alert('hi');` then the C# equivilent would be `someBool && MessageBox.Show("hi");` which won't compile for multiple reasons, you can't && a bool and a void, and also you can't have an && expression then discard the result.

Comment: "if performs an evalutation upon a condition and RETURNS, ahem, a bool" that is just a completely false statement.  In a javascript console, do `a = true;` then `if(a) {alert('something')};' the return value of that expression says `undefined` in Firebug.

Comment: Yes, you can only shortcircuit conditions that when evalutated would return bool. The main reason I removed the C# comment is because && has overloaded meanings in JavaScript that C# does not have. One such overloaded meanings (viz., the one is in your question) has no equivalent in C#.

Comment: That's not what I said: it returns a bool for the evalutation of the condition

Comment: Here is the kind of example I had in mind for C# where if is not used but && is used to evaluate a chain of expressions: return (valueAsString != null && valueAsString.Length >= _minCharacters);

Comment: @Carno I understand that, but again that isn't what the question is asking about.  If you notice there is neither assignment or a return in my example.  What you're describing is just the normal use of a short-circuited `and` operator that's used in most languages. The question is specifically about when you throw away the result of the the && and use it purely for the side-effects.  I thought that was clear by just having that alone as a full statement without a return and without doing anything with the result of the && but maybe I should have been more explicit in what I meant.

Answer (score -1):

By default, it will trigger a jshint warning:

> [jshint] Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. (W030) [W030]

However personally, I prefer the short-circuit version, ***it looks more declarative and has "less control logic"***, might be a misconception though.