# var exists or var gets value syntax?

Tags: javascript

I came across the following line of code in the underscore.js source:

```
function (obj, iterator, context) {
  iterator || (iterator = _.identity);
  ...
}
```

Is that syntax equivalent to:

```
if (!iterator) {
  iterator = _.identity;
}
```

Are there any performance benefits to using the former syntax other than reducing the statement to one line?

Comment: wouldn't it be `if(!iterator) { ...` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using &&'s short-circuiting as an if statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049006/using-s-short-circuiting-as-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is functionally equivalent to that.

The only benefit to doing it this way is that your check takes up two less lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is an effect of [boolean short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Basically, the evaluation of a boolean expression stops as soon as its outcome is determined:

```
true || func()
```

In this case, func() is never called, because whatever it returns, the value of the whole expression will still be `true`.

```
false && func()
```

Similarly, in this case func() is also not called at all, because no matter what it returns, the expression will remain `false`.

Comment: Ahh thank you for the proper terminology. It turns out that this question has indeed been asked before.