# Does JavaScript have "Short-circuit" evaluation?

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

I would like to know if JavaScript has "short-circuit" evaluation like `&&`-operator in C#. If not, I would like to know if there is a workaround that makes sense to adopt.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added `https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%s` as a search shortcut (Chrome/Firefox) to speed up searches.

Comment: Also here an answer to my question https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Further useful resources: [The || evaluation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation) [The && evaluation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049006/using-s-short-circuiting-as-an-if-statement#)

Comment: Closely related: [Logical operators in JavaScript — how do you use them?](/q/4535647/4642212).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript has "short-circuit" evaluation.

```
if (true || foo.foo){
    // Passes, no errors because foo isn't defined.
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLvbY/)

```
if (false && foo.foo){
    // Also passes, no errors because foo isn't defined.
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLvbY/1/)

Comment: So short circuit it is the standard in JS?

Comment: @GibboK. Don't know what you mean by standard, you can't change that behavior, it's the only behavior. (just like with C# by the way)

Comment: Thanks gdoron, please help me to understand ... in C# I have also binary operator like & so both the operand must be true to pass, instead with && in C

Comment: @GibboK. Then, obviously, there can't be a `Short-circuit` with that logic operator. Just try it yourself. Use my demo.

Comment: @GibboK: Check out this [operator reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript). And yes, there is a binary AND operator in JS as well.

Comment: And in both javascript and C#, & is a _bitwise_ AND operator. It can return FALSE even if both arguments are true.

Comment: @GibboK. YES in the standard! But good comment, as in times of JIT-compiling-magic in javascript implementations, one does really want to know if something is "the standard" , or potentially subject to the implementation. The way a condition statement with Binary Logical Operators is evaluated and (short-curcuit) is a standard behavior http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11

Comment: Ancient thread, but actually in C# '&' with boolean operands does non-short-circuit evaluation. With integer operands it does bitwise.

Comment: Here is my article that explains short circuits. Hope it can help http://pogsdotnet.blogspot.com/2015/08/javascript-short-circuiting.html

Comment: I would like to add that the shorter version is very useful in reactjs render and other scenarios, here some examples https://jsfiddle.net/twpvkmfq/1/  (vanilla)

Comment: Is there a special reason for `true == true` instead of `true`? If not, I would prefer the shorter variant

Answer (score 60):

The answer is yes!

This answer goes into great detail on how [short-circuiting](/questions/tagged/short-circuiting) works in JavaScript, with all the gotchas and also relevant themes such as operator precedence.
*If you’re looking for a quick definition and already understand how short-circuiting works, I’d recommend checking other answers.*

---

### What we (thought we) knew so far:

First let’s inspect the behavior we are all familiar with, inside the `if` condition, where we use `&&` to check whether the two expressions are `true`:

```js
const expr1 = true;
const expr2 = true;

if (expr1 && expr2) {
  console.log("bar");
}
```

Now, your first instinct is probably to say: *“Ah yes, quite simple, the code executes the statement if both `expr1` and `expr2` are evaluated as `true`“*.

Well, yes and no. You are technically correct, that is the behavior you described, **but that’s not exactly how the code is evaluated** and we’ll need to delve deeper in order to fully understand.

### How exactly is the `&&` and `||` interpreted?

It’s time to look “under the hood” of the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) engine.
Let’s consider this practical example:

```js
function sanitize(x) {
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    return NaN;
  }

  return x;
}

let userInput = 0xFF; // As an example.
const res = sanitize(userInput) && userInput + 5

console.log(res);
```

Well, the result is `260`, but why?
In order to get the answer, we need to understand how the short-circuit evaluation works.

By the [MDN definition](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND), the `&&` operator in `expr1 && expr2` performs as follows:

> Logical AND (`&&`) evaluates operands from left to right, returning immediately with the value of the first [falsy](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Falsy) operand it encounters; if all values are [truthy](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy), the value of the last operand is returned.
>
> If a value can be converted to `true`, the value is so-called [truthy](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy).
> If a value can be converted to `false`, the value is so-called [falsy](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Falsy).
>
> […]
>
> As each operand is converted to a boolean, if the result of one conversion is found to be `false`, the AND operator stops and returns the original value of that falsy operand; it does **not** evaluate any of the remaining operands.

Or, more simply, in an [older revision](//web.archive.org/web/20190504233206/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) of the documentation:

> | Operator | Syntax | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Logical AND (`&&`) | `expr1 && expr2` | If `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr2`; else, returns `expr1`. |

So this means, in our practical example, the `const res` is evaluated the following way:

1. Invoke *`expr1`*, which is `sanitize(userInput)`, or `sanitize(0xFF)`.
2. Run `sanitize(0xFF)`: check `isNaN(x)`, or `isNaN(0xFF)`, (which results in `false` because `0xFF` is a valid hexadecimal number literal for 255), return `x` which is `0xFF`, or `255`. If `isNaN(x)` was `true`, `sanitize` would’ve returned `NaN`.
3. The `expr1` resulted in `255`, a “truthy” value, so it’s time to evaluate `expr2`. If `NaN` was returned, it’d *stop* as `NaN` is falsy.
4. Since `sanitize(userInput)` is truthy (a non-zero, finite number), keep going and add `5` to `userInput`.

“Truthy” means that expression can be evaluated as true.

So here, we were able to avoid additional `if` blocks and further `isNaN` checks with a simple usage of the `&&` operator.

#### How it really works:

By now, we should at least have a picture how the [short-circuit](/questions/tagged/short-circuit) operators work.

The operators that exhibit short-circuiting behavior are:

- [Logical AND (`&&`)](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)
- [Logical OR (`||`)](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)
- [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)
- [Optional chaining (`?.`)](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

The universal rule goes:

- `a && b &&` … `&& z` evaluates to the **first falsy** operand, or to the **last** operand if none is found to be falsy.
- `a || b ||` … `|| z` evaluates to the **first truthy** operand, or to the **last** operand if none is found to be truthy.
- `a ?? b ??` … `?? z` evaluates to the **first** operand which is neither `null` nor `undefined`, or to the **last** operand, otherwise.
- `a?.b?.`…`?.z` accesses each property in the chain and evaluates to the value of the nested `z` property if all previous links of the chain evaluate to something that can be converted to an object (i.e. neither `null` nor `undefined`); otherwise it returns `undefined`, regardless of which nested property fails.

Here are some further examples for better comprehension:

```js
function a() {
  console.log("a");

  return false;
}

function b() {
  console.log("b");

  return true;
}

if (a() && b()){
   console.log("foobar"); 
}

// `a()` is evaluated as `false`; execution is stopped.
```

```js
function a() {
  console.log("a");

  return false;
}

function b() {
  console.log("b");

  return true;
}

if (a() || b()){
   console.log("foobar"); 
}

/*
** 1. `a()` is evaluated as `false`.
** 2. So it should evaluate `expr2`, which is `b()`.
** 3. `b()` is evaluated `true`.
** 4. The statement `console.log("foobar");` is executed.
*/
```

```js
function a() {
  console.log("a");

  return null;
}

function b() {
  console.log("b");

  return false;
}

function c() {
  console.log("c");

  return true;
}

if (a() ?? b() ?? c()){
   console.log("foobar"); 
}

/*
** 1. `a()` is evaluated as `null`.
** 2. So it should evaluate `expr2`, which is `b()`.
** 3. `b()` is evaluated as `false`; execution is stopped.
*/
```

```js
const deeply = {
    get nested(){
      console.log("nested");
      
      return {
        get object(){
          console.log("object");
          
          return null;
        }
      };
    }
  };

if (deeply?.nested?.object?.but?.not?.that?.deep){
   console.log("foobar"); 
}

/*
** 1. `deeply` is evaluated as an object.
** 2. `deeply?.nested` is evaluated as an object.
** 3. `deeply?.nested?.object` is evaluated as `null`.
** 4. `?.but?.not?.that?.deep` is essentially skipped over; the entire optional chain is evaluated as `undefined`; execution is stopped.
*/
```

---

### One last pesky, but very important thing: [Operator precedence](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Nice, hopefully you’re getting the hang of it!
Last thing we need to know is a rule about operator precedence, that is: **The `&&` operator is always evaluated prior to the `||` operator.**

Consider the following example:

```js
function a() { console.log("a"); return true;}
function b() { console.log("b"); return false;}
function c() { console.log("c"); return false;}

console.log(a() || b() && c());

// "a" is logged; execution is stopped.
```

The expression `a() || b() && c()` will, perhaps confusingly to some, result in `a()`.
The reason is quite simple, it’s just our eyesight that’s kind of deceiving us, because we’re used to reading left-to-right.
Let’s take the `console.log()` and what not out and focus purely on the evaluation:

```js
true || false && false
```

`&&` having a higher precedence than `||` means that the *operands closest to `&&`* are evaluated first — but *after* all operations with an *even higher* precedence already being evaluated.
Since there’re only `&&` and `||` here, these are just `false` and `false`.

`||` works the same way, including the rule that all operations with an *even higher* precedence should already be evaluated.

1. So *first*, we need to evaluate `false && false`, which is just `false`.
2. *Then* we evaluate `true || false` (with the *resulting* `false`), which is `true`.
3. The whole expression is equivalent to `(true || (false && false))`, which is `(true || (false))`, which is `(true)`.

You can also try an alternative perspective: in the [ECMAScript specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-LogicalORExpression) (which is what the JavaScript language is based on), the expression `expr1 || expr2` follows a pattern called the *LogicalORExpression*.
Following its definition, in simple terms, both `expr1` and `expr2` are their own *LogicalANDExpression*.

1. If you wanted to evaluate something like `true || false && false`, you’d have to evaluate the *LogicalORExpression*: (`true`) `||` (`false && false`).
   You know that (`true`) is just `true`, but you don’t immediately know what (`false && false`) is.
2. So then, you’d have to evaluate the *LogicalANDExpression*: (`false`) `&&` (`false`).
   And now you’re done, because (`false`) is just `false`.

Only once you know the result of evaluating each *LogicalANDExpression*, you can move on to evaluate the constituting *LogicalORExpression*.
This is exactly what is meant by `&&` being evaluated before `||`, or `&&` having a higher precedence than `||`.

*(NB: These [grammar rules](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) kill two birds with one stone: they define the evaluation order (via recursive definitions)* and *the operator precedence (in this case: left to right, and `&&` before `||`).)*

Well, that might seem pretty tricky, all because of a few weird rules and semantics.
But remember, you can always escape operator precedence with parentheses, also known as the [grouping operator `(`…`)`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) — *just like in math*.

```js
function a() { console.log("a"); return true; }
function b() { console.log("b"); return false; }
function c() { console.log("c"); return false; }

console.log((a() || b()) && c());

/*
** 1. The parenthesized part is evaluated first.
** 2. `a()` is evaluated as `true`, so `b()` is skipped
** 3. `c()` is evaluated as `false`, stops execution.
*/
```

And we have yet to talk about where to place the `??` operator in terms of precedence!
But don’t worry: since operator precedence rules between `&&` *and* `||` *and* `??` would be too confusing and too complicated, it is actually *not allowed* to put them next to each other!
They can only appear together in the same expression if it’s very clear which one is evaluated first.

```js
(a ?? b) && c  // Clearly, `(a ?? b)` is evaluated first.
a ?? (b && c)  // Clearly, `(b && c)` is evaluated first.
a ?? b && c    // Unclear! Throws a SyntaxError.
```

Comment: This is the right answer with a deep explanation, should be marked as accepted and upvoted much more than it is currently!

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Only part that's unclear for me is the last example of Operator precedence.

Comment: I’ve edited this and have hopefully addressed all concerns from comments: better variable names, an explicit answer, correct hex number value, correct precedence explanation. Also updated MDN link and quote, put more accurate phrasings and a more in-depth view of precedence into the post (plus minor editorial changes). _Most importantly_, this answer finally mentions the **optional chaining (`?.`) and nullish-coalescing (`??`)** operators! Honestly, this answer feels a bit much now, even if `&&=`, `||=`, and `??=` aren’t mentioned yet; maybe the detail about precedence isn’t needed that much.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks a lot, it's been a while since the answer was posted and sadly I didn't get around to updating it with how busy I've been. But I just wanted to stop by and show my gratitude. Yeah it's becoming almost a MDN page of it's own, but I still find with the original post and the awesome updates over the years, it's become one of the best and concise answers to short chaining in JS on the internet :-)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that logical expressions are read left-to-right, and if the value of the left condition is enough to get the total value, the right condition will not be processed and evaluated. Some very simple examples:

```js
function test() {
    const caseNumber = document.querySelector('#sel').value;
    const userChoice = () => confirm('Press OK or Cancel');
    if (caseNumber === '1') {
        console.log (1 === 1 || userChoice());
    } else if (caseNumber === '2') {
        console.log (1 === 2 && userChoice());
    } else if (caseNumber === '3') {
        console.log (1 === 2 || userChoice());
    } else if (caseNumber === '4') {
        console.log (1 === 1 && userChoice());
    } else if (caseNumber === '5') {
        console.log (userChoice() || 1 === 1);
    } else if (caseNumber === '6') {
        console.log (userChoice() && 1 === 2);
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="sel">Select a number of a test case and press "RUN!":</label>
<br><select id="sel">
  <option value="">Unselected</option>
  <option value="1">Case 1</option>
  <option value="2">Case 2</option>
  <option value="3">Case 3</option>
  <option value="4">Case 4</option>
  <option value="5">Case 5</option>
  <option value="6">Case 6</option>
</select>
<button onclick="test()">RUN!</button>
```

The first two cases above will print to console results `true` and `false` respectively and you will not even see the modal window asking you to press "OK" or "Cancel", because the left condition is sufficient to define the total result.
On the contrary, with the cases 3–6, you will see the modal window asking for your choice, because the former two depend on the right part (that is your choice), and the latter two — regardless of the fact that the aggregate values of these expressions do not depend on your choice — because left conditions are read first. So, it is important to place conditions left-to-right based on which ones you want to be processed first.