# what does variableFoo && functionBar() do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, comparison, expression

I have come across some Javascript code recently that looks like this:

```
var foo = 'blah';

bar = function(){
   // append some content to the body   
}

doStuff = function(){

   if(somethingIsTrue){
    // do something
   } else {
    // do something else       
   }

   foo && bar();
}

doStuff();
```

The foo && bar() expression logs to the console as 'undefined'.

I get why it might call the bar function to run from inside the doStuff function but why is it used as a comparison expression with the foo variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means call `bar()` only if `foo` is defined.

Basically the same as:

```
if (foo){
    bar();
}
```

Comment: +1. It's quite a common pattern I think, while I find the benefits (short) aren't worth loosing in readibility...

Comment: I agree the readability in this case is poor, and you aren't gaining much.  The "or" version, IMO, o.k. cause it is so useful to test for missing data or nulls and use a default, e.g.  `currency = someoption.currency || 'dollars'`.

Comment: @user949300 I don't think `or` would make sense in this case, since `foo` is the condition for evaluating `bar()`.

Comment: @remyabel I think user949300 is just talking about the common practice to use `||` as a way to assign default values. Similar concept to using `&&` as a stand in for an `if...else`, but I don't think he's suggesting that they're interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation)

Javascript uses short-circuit evaluation. That means that if `foo` evaluates to a truthy value (i.e., it's defined), then it will evaluate `bar`.

Comment: More accurate to say *if foo is true-ish, then it will evaluate bar*

Comment: @Mike OK fixed I think.

Answer (score 2):

It makes use of the short circuiting logic of `&&`.  Because if the left hand side of the `&&` expression is `false`, we already know the value of the entire expression is `false` so we don't need to evaluate the right hand side.  So this will evaluate to the left hand side if `foo` is falsy and the right hand side if `foo` is truthy.

In simple terms, it can be thought of as:

```
if (foo) bar();
```

but it's also an expression, so it's more like:

```
foo ? bar() : foo
```

or

```
(function () {
  if (foo) return bar()
  else return foo
}())
```

You can also do the reverse using `||` which is more like:

```
if (!foo) bar()
```

or

```
(function () {
  if (foo) return foo
  else return bar()
}())
```