# How do I read this?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand a jQuery plugin and I'm seeing things like this all over the un-minified source:

```
"y" === self.options.direction && node.stop().scrollTop(floorActive * WH),
"x" === self.options.direction && (node.stop().scrollLeft(floorActive * WW), nodeChildren.each(function(index) {
    $(this).css("left", index * WW);
})), chocolate && (nodeChildren.each(function(index) {
    $(this).css({
        left: self.options.direction[index][1] * WW,
        top: self.options.direction[index][0] * WH
    });
}), node.stop().scrollLeft(self.options.direction[floorActive][1] * WW).scrollTop(self.options.direction[floorActive][0] * WH));
```

I see things similar to this everywhere too:

```
return $.each(floorCollection, function() {
    (!floor || Math.abs(this[axis] - goal) > Math.abs(floor[axis] - goal)) && (floor = this);
}), floor && -1 !== directionArray.indexOf(floor) ? directionArray.indexOf(floor) : false;
```

How would these things normally be written out in a more traditional syntax?

Comment: Are you talking about the anonymous functions?

Comment: Yes. What are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Or is the [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) tripping you up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different things going on here - I'd agree that most of them aren't necessarily best practice.

- The author appears to be using [commas to group expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781624/380487), which effectively puts them into a single statement.
- The author is using [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101852/what-does-variablefoo-functionbar-do-in-javascript/20101978#20101978) of `condition && statement` to mean `if (condition) { statement }`. Using commas and parentheses allows `condition && (expression, expression, expression)` to be the same as `if (condition) { statement; statement; statement; }`. This leads to some less-than-legible code like `... && (floor = this)`, where a statement is wrapped in parentheses to allow it to be evaluated as an expression.
- The author is using left-hand comparison, i.e. `5 == x` instead of `x == 5`. One advantage of this is that mistaken use of `=` instead of `==` is a syntax error.
- The author is using short-circuit evaluation within comparisons, i.e. `(a || b) > foo`, which compares `a` if `a` is truthy or `b` otherwise.

All of this is valid, none of it is particularly recommended in my opinion. The commas in particular seem like a really illegible approach.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is greatly appreciated and helped my to understand how the code is being parsed.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are talking about, but here is the code more readable:

```
if ("y" === self.options.direction) {
    node
        .stop()
        .scrollTop(floorActive * WH);
}
if ("x" === self.options.direction) {
    node
        .stop()
        .scrollLeft(floorActive * WW);
    nodeChildren.each(function(index) {
        $(this).css("left", index * WW);
    });
}
if (chocolate) {
    nodeChildren.each(function(index) {
        $(this).css({
            left: self.options.direction[index][1] * WW,
            top: self.options.direction[index][0] * WH
        });
    });
    node
        .stop()
        .scrollLeft(self.options.direction[floorActive][1] * WW)
        .scrollTop(self.options.direction[floorActive][0] * WH);
}
```

And the second one:

```
$.each(floorCollection, function() {
    if (!floor || Math.abs(this[axis] - goal) > Math.abs(floor[axis] - goal)) {
        floor = this;
    }
});
if (floor && -1 !== directionArray.indexOf(floor)) {
    return directionArray.indexOf(floor);
} else {
    return false;
}
```