# How to ignore disabled checkbox values while looping

Tags: javascript, html

**below is my code:**

```
Cell.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
Cell.setAttribute('name', "Size");
```

based on condition I will set some values to 'checked' and 'disabled'.

```
Cell.setAttribute('checked', 'true');
Cell.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
```

Here 'Size' contains some values which are disabled, both unchecked and checked.

So whenever I am trying to retrieve the checked values, the default disabled 
checked boxes are also being returned.

I just want the checked values; not the disabled checked values in SelectedDetails method:

```
var testCaseArray =[]; 
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('Size');

for(var i=0; i<checkbox.length; i++){
    if(checkbox[i].checked){ 
        testCaseArray.push(checkbox[i].value);
    }
}

return testCaseArray;
```

Comment: var testCaseArray =[];
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('Size');
    for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){
     if(checkbox[i].checked){
         testCaseArray.push(checkbox[i].value);   
        }   
    }
    return testCaseArray;

Comment: Place the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve all checked checkbox elements in a series, except the disabled one(s), into an `Array`:

```
var chkd = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'))
            .filter(function(e) {
               return null == e.getAttribute('disabled');
             });
```

You can also use this selector to retrieve a Array-like list with the same selection:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input:checked:not(disabled)')
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/vcERs/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in the check for disabled, as well as the check for it being checked

```
var testCaseArray =[]; 
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('Size');

for(var i=0; i<checkbox.length; i++){
    if(checkbox[i].disabled){
        continue;
    }
    if(checkbox[i].checked){ 
        testCaseArray.push(checkbox[i].value);
    }
}

return testCaseArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [JavaScript has *short-circuit evaluation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation), just add the condition to your `if` statement:

```
var testCaseArray = [],
    checkbox = document.getElementsByName('Size');

for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; ++i) {
    if (!checkbox[i].disabled && checkbox[i].checked) {
        testCaseArray.push(checkbox[i].value);
    }
}

return testCaseArray;
```

The JavaScript engine will automatically stop evaluating if `!checkbox[i].disabled` returns false.