# Is it safe to use || instead of if? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Recently, I have noticed, that putting an **or** operator between two functions, will make the second one run only if the first side of the operator is **false**. Is it safe to use this instead of **if** statements?

Example:

```
function a(){ return Math.random() >= 0.5; } 
function b(){ console.log("foo"); }
```

Using

`!a() || b();`

has the same behaviour as

```
if( a() ) b();
```

My question is: Is it safe to use this syntax? Are there exceptions?

Comment: "Is it safe to use this syntax?" Yes.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with it logically or syntactically, you may lose readability or introduce confusion in some cases.

Comment: `a() && b()` is probably better :P and *very* slightly more readable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to rely on this (although the readability is open to debate and depends on the exact use case).

This behaviour is called ["short-circuit evaluation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and is a feature of many programming languages. See [Does JavaScript have "Short-circuit" evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation)