# Nested return performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Given these two functions in JavaScript:

```
function (){
  return _.includes(someLongArray, value) && someSimpleValue;
}
```

VS

```
function (){
  return someSimpleValue && _.includes(someLongArray, value);
}
```

Which of those is going to have better performance? 
When the `someSimpleValue` is false, is it going to call the return automatically? Or is it going to verify if the second one is true or false (Useless cause when a `&&` has some of them false it can't be truthy anymore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second is more efficient because using the '&&' operator will short-circuit if the first condition evaluates to false.

Further reading/duplicate:

[Does JavaScript have "Short-circuit" evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation)

Answer (score 2):

**The second is faster**

When using the **&&** operator javascript checks the left side, if it's true checks the right side - if it's false it doesn't check the right side.

*As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:*

*false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.*

[full article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: I think you mean the other way around. If the left is false it never evaluates the right.

Answer (score 0):

The second one will be faster because of "short-circuit" and as soon as the first condition is false it "exits"