# JavaScript && operator: will it prevent computing of following conditionals?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a conditional like this:

```
if (conditionOne && conditionTwo) { 
  // execute some code
}
```

If `conditionOne` is false, does that prevent computing `conditionTwo`? In many cases I **don't** want to compute `conditionTwo` because it would throw an error if `conditionOne` is false. For example, often times I want to make sure a particular property exists before I do anything with it. In the past I've used nested conditionals, but the && would save space and look cleaner in a lot of cases. I just want to make sure the second contrition will be left alone if the first is false.

Comment: *If conditionOne is false, does that prevent computing conditionTwo?* **Yes**.

Comment: Another duplicate here: [Does Javascript have short circuit evalution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If conditionOne is false, does that prevent computing conditionTwo?

Yes, it does.  This is referred to as short circuiting.

A common idom in Javascript is exactly what you are discussing:

```
if (obj && obj.method) {
   obj.method();
}
```

If `obj` is not truthy, then `obj.method` will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All the logical operators in ECMAScript short circuit.

```
'use strict';

function test(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
  return arg === 'true';
}

if (test('false') && test('true')) {
  console.log('Inside && if\'s body');
}

if (test('true') || test('false')) {
  console.log('Inside || if\'s body');
}
```

**Output**

```
false
true
Inside || if's body
```

In the `&&`'s `if` case, the first condition itself is failing. So the second one is not executed.

In the `||`'s `if` case, the first condition itself is successful. So the second one is not executed.