# Correctness of !args.value || args.value.length?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm reviewing [this line of code](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/63e173c806bdfc879d13a0069debb73f4a757bf6/src/validation/ValidationTypes.ts#L235).  It has an expression that looks like this:

```
!args.value || args.value.length
```

For example suppose we do this:

```
let v = {};
console.log(!v.value);  //logs true
console.log(v.value);  //logs undefined
console.log(v.value.length); //Script wont run - cannot read property length of undefined
```

So even though value is undefined, we are proceeding to check that args.value.length (or undefined> is less than the constraint?  So effectively we could be checking something like this ( IIUC ):

```
    true             throws
!undefined || undefined.length < 4
```

So I thought the purpose of the first check in the statement was to make sure that the `undefined` is actually defined?

So in other words it should be `args.value && args.value.length`?  Or stated differently:

> if args.value exists, then check the length of it?

Here's the entire snippet in context just for completeness:

```
if (isMinLength && (!args.value || args.value.length < args.constraints[0])) {
return eachPrefix + "$property must be longer than or equal to $constraint1 characters";
```

Comment: If `args.value` is falsy then that error holds (it's not longer, because there's nothing there). Or, if the length is less than the constraint, then that error holds too... Am I missing something? The second condition would only be evaluated if the previous is falsy, which would happen if `args.value` is truthy

Comment: The condition is correct. `args.value` is optional and `args.value.length` is checked only if `args.value` is set. If it is not set the the test passes (no limit set). Changing it as you suggest makes `args.value` required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<` has higher precedence than `||`:

```
if (isMinLength && (!args.value || (args.value.length < args.constraints[0]))) {
//                                 ^                                       ^
```

So the condition matches if either `args.value` doesn't exist, *or* when its `.length` is too small.

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled, because if args.value is undefined, then args.value.length will throw an unchecked exception right?  I also updated the question to reflect this concern.  But judging by your SO score, I"m probably missing something ...

Comment: @Ole If `args.value` is falsy and `!args.value` evaluates to `true`, the right hand side [won't be evaluated at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation).

Comment: Oooh ... Got it ... OK Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At first its actually

```
!args.value || (args.value.length < args.constraints[0])
```

But you are right, the only difference to

```
args.value && args.value.length < args.constraints[0]
```

Is that the first always returns `false` while the second returns `undefined` if args.value is not defined. As you use that in an if statement, the outcome doesnt really matter.