# Javascript || operator behavior

Tags: javascript

How can this be explained

These two are as expected

```
"x" || "y"
=> "x"

"x" || "y" == "y"
=> "x"
```

But this?

```
"x" || "y" == "y" ? "a" : "b"
=> "a"
```

Edit: I was expecting "x" for the last expression. Now got the answer. I was not clear with the operator precedence of ? and ||

Comment: `?` before `||`

Comment: You need to read about ternary operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: It just says `if ("x" || "y" == "y") "a" else "b"`.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you are confused about the result? What were you expecting? It's not clear what you're actually asking - do you need clarification on ternary operators? Are you confused because of how the expressions are grouped? Is it a matter of JS's truthy and falsy values?

Comment: I think you want `("x" || "y") == "y"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look in operator precedence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

```
"x" || "y" == "y"
```

is `"x"` and it is truthy ([Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy)), so `... ? ... : ...` returns first expression

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down.

```
//Your original question
"x" || "y" == "y" ? "a" : "b"

//Changing ternary to standard "if"
if ("x" || "y" == "y") then "a" else "b"

//Grouping the conditionals
if ( ("x") || ("y" == "y") ) then "a" else "b"

//Evaluating the conditionals
if ( true || true ) then "a" else "b"

//End result
if (true) then "a" else "b"
```

- `"x"` evaluates to `true` because non-empty strings are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).
- The expression is grouped as such because the *Logical OR operator* (`||`) has an operator precedence of **5**, whereas the *Conditional operator* (`... ? ... : ...`) has an operator precedence of **4**. ([More on operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence))

It's hard to know exactly what you were expecting, however I'd imagine it might be this:

```js
var result = "x" || ("y" == "y" ? "a" : "b");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"x" || "y" == "y" ? "a" : "b"
```

According to the [operator precedence rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), in this expression the evaluation happens in the following order:

1. `==` - equality check: `"y" == "y"` this evaluates to `true` so you have the following expression left to solve `"x" || true ? "a" : "b"`

```js
console.log("y" == "y")
```

2. `||` - boolean OR: `"x" || true` [this evaluates to `"x"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) - the first expression is truthy, so the OR is short circuited and it returns the value of the expression.

```js
console.log("x" || true)
```

3. `?` - [ternary conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator): `"x" ? "a" : "b"` - since `"x"` is truthy, as we already saw, then this passes the ternary test and returns the left value `"a"`.

```js
console.log("x" ? "a" : "b")
```

So, for clarity the original statement can be re-written as

```
("x" || ("y" == "y")) ? "a" : "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

`||` operator is evaluated left-to-right, and is [short-circuited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation). Therefore first time it encounters a true condition, it returns without evaluating others. Since "x" is not an empty string, it returns true, and all behind is never evaluated.
The latter syntax is [the conditionnal ternary operaor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
condition ? exprT : exprF
```

which returns exprT if condition is true and exprF if condition is false

Answer (score 0):

**OR Condition (||)** : Whenever the first condition is True. It will execute that block of code. It will not check the other condition After || Operator .

**AND Condition (&&)** : Whenever the first condition is False. It will execute that block of code. It will not check the other condition After && Operator.