# How to remove CSS 'active' class if clicked element is already 'active'?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with a mapped array, assigning an 'active' class to an element when it's clicked (setting `activeIndex` to the element's index).

But if an element's index is already the value of `activeIndex` when it's clicked, I want to remove the 'active' class. Currently, when I click the same element a second time, the 'active' class is not removed.

```
class People extends Component {
    state = {
        people: [],
        activeIndex: null,
    };

    personClickHandler = (index) => {
        this.setState({activeIndex: index})
    };

    render() {
        let people = this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
            return (
                <Person
                    name={person.name}
                    cat={person.cat}
                    key={index}
                    index={index}
                    active={this.state.activeIndex}
                    clicked={() => this.personClickHandler(index)} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className={classes.People}>
                {people}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**What I've tried:**

I know I need to do some sort of state comparison. My initial thought was to compare the current value of `activeIndex` with `prevState.activeIndex` inside the click event handler, but I'm still running into the same issue, where the class never gets *removed* if the element is clicked a second time.

```
personClickHandler = (index) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        activeIndex: (prevState.index !== index) ? index : null,
    }));

    this.setState({activeIndex: index})
};
```

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: `active={this.state.activeIndex === index}`, then in your Person component, if active is not false, it will add the class name otherwise it wont: className=`{active ? 'active' : ''}`. Also take a look at this: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames it will make your code cleaner too

Comment: @LucianoSemerini It would be simpler to write `className={active && 'active'}` since you wouldn't be assigning a value if not active.

Comment: Indeed. Classnames package is quite nice too to write this nice and clean. Specially if you later have to add multiple conditional class names

Answer (score 0):

First you need a way to dynamically determine if the current Person in the map is the active one. To do that, simply equate the value of `this.state.activeIndex` to the current map `index` with `this.state.activeIndex === index`.

If you do this, you won't need any special logic in the click function's `setState`. Just keep it exactly as you have it in your first code sample.

Now that each Person will know if it's active or not, you can use [short-circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12554578/4881192) logic to add the `active` class to the clicked Person with `className={active && 'active'}`.

```
// People.jsx
personClickHandler = (index) => {
  this.setState({ activeIndex: index }) // No need to involve previous state
}

render() {
  let people = this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
    return (
      <Person
        name={person.name}
        key={index}
        active={index === this.state.activeIndex} // Pass boolean for each Person
        clicked={() => this.personClickHandler(index)} />
    )
  })
  ...
}
```

```
// Person.jsx
render() {
  let active = this.props.active

  return (
    <div
      className={active && 'active'} // Short-circuit logic
      onClick={this.props.clicked}>
      {this.props.name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's a [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wqvrm2v3z5) of this code.