# What kind of conditional rendering is this for JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What is this concept called and how do I read it?

```
        {!auth.loading && user === auth.user._id && (
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">
            <i className="fas fa-times"></i>
          </button>
        )}
```

My guess, is "if auth is not loading, and user equals auth.user then show the button", but why? What does the double ampersand mean?

Comment: It means `and`. Some REPL experimentation would explain this immediately, e.g., `"truthy" && "more truthy" && "wat"`. It's a short-hand notation, convenient for simple expressions in JSX. (Although I'd personally extract out the first two parts of the expression.)

Comment: [It is well explained there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

Comment: That link is just basic operators. I know booleans, I just have not ever seen it written out like this where something after the && gets executed or returned

Comment: @mastercool That's what *always* happens with logical expressions; the result is the last thing evaluated that satisfies the condition, as explained on MDN or the REPL example in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of AND operator, expression is evaluated until one of the condition evaluates to false because the result will always be false, independent of the further conditions.

the expression will be evaluated from left to right and will [short-circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation), i.e. evaluation of the expression will stop, as soon as any of the sub-expression evaluates to false.

JSX will be rendered if:

1. `auth.loading` is false

AND

2. `user === auth.user._id` is true

You could understand the conditional rendering as:

```
(first expression) && (second expression) && JSX
```

if first expression evaluates to false, no further evaluation will be done because one of the operand of `&&` operator has already evaluated to false.

Similarly, if first expression evaluates to true but second expression is false, no JSX will be rendered.

If first expression evaluates to true and second expression also evaluates to true, then `true && true && JSX` will evaluate to `JSX`

You can look at the [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) section of React docs for details.

Answer (score 0):

The double ampersand(`&&`) means the [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND).

The code you've provided uses short-circuit evaluation to determine whether to render the `button` or not. To simplify the code if `auth.loading` is false and `user === auth.user._id` is true then the `button` will be rendered.

***More details on short-circuit evaluation with logical AND operator***

`expression 1 && expression 2`

In the case above if `expression 1` is falsy `expression 2` will not be evaluated, because whether the `expression 2` evaluates to true of false the result of the combined expression will be `false` because both the expression needs to be true for the combined expression to evaluate to true.

Example,

```js
const funcOne = () => { console.log('called funcOne'); return false; }
const funcTwo = () => { console.log('called funcTwo'); return true; }

console.log( funcOne() && funcTwo() );

// in the case above funcTwo will not be called because 
// the firstpart of the expression funcOne() && funcTwo()
// evaluates to false (the return value of funcOne is false)
```

**The usage of short-circuit evaluation with React**

Keep in mind `JSX` is just syntactic sugar for function call, `<button>Hello</button>` will be converted to a `React.createElement` function call behinds the scene. That is why it is nothing different to render `JSX` with short-circuit evaluation than using short-circuit evaluation with regular function calls.

```
expr1 && expr2 && <button>Hello</button>

// will be converted to
expr1 && expr2 && React.createElement("button", null, "Hello");

// so if expr1 or expr2 evaluate to false React.createElement will not be -
// called, both expr1 and expr2 have to evaluate to true for the- 
// React.createElement function to be called
```