# Refactor javascript code more elegantly, not using nested ternary expression or let

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, refactoring, conditional-operator

I have this simplified code, quite simple:

```
export const OwnRedirect = () => {
  const { pipelineType, ticketId, productId } = useParams<{
    pipelineType?: string;
    ticketId?: string;
    productId?: string;
  }>();
  let path = '';
  if (pipelineType) {
    path = `/pipeline/${pipelineType}`;
  } else if (ticketId) {
    path = `/ticket/${ticketId}`;
  } else if (productId) {
    path = `/product/${productId}`;
  } else {
    path = '/pipeline/local';
  }
  return <Redirect to={path}/>;
};
```

But I found it not readable enough. Anybody has an idea how to refactor this code not using `if` or `switch` or `let` or nested ternary operator?

Comment: Providing the most minimal/simple instance of your problem enhances the chance to get good answers.

Comment: Already edited.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to read, you can take advantage of [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation) with `&&` and `||`. To make things cleaner and easier to test, I also like creating really small functions that only do one thing, but do it well. It avoids mixing logic *(which path to choose)* and functionality *(building those paths)*:

```
export const OwnRedirect = () => {
  const { pipelineType, ticketId, productId } = useParams<{
    pipelineType?: string;
    ticketId?: string;
    productId?: string;
  }>();
  
  const path = (
    (pipelineType && buildPipelinePath(pipelineType)) ||
    (ticketId     && buildTicketPath(ticketId)      ) ||
    (productId    && buildProductPath(productId)    ) ||
    `/pipeline/local`
  );

  return <Redirect to={path} />;
};

function buildPipelinePath(pipelineType) {
  return `/pipeline/${Number(pipelineType) === 1 ? 'local' : 'global'}`;
}

function buildTicketPath(ticketId) {
  return `/ticket/${ticketId}`;
}

function buildProductPath(productId) {
  return `/product/${productId}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes just separating it into a function
helps with readability.

```js
const toUrl = ({ pipelineType = '', ticketId = '', productId = '' }) => {
  if (pipelineType) {
    return `/pipeline/${pipelineType}`;
  } 
  
  if (ticketId) {
    return `/ticket/${ticketId}`;
  } 
  
  if (productId) {
    return `/product/${productId}`;
  }
  
  return '/pipeline/local';
}


export const OwnRedirect = () => {
  const params = useParams<{
    pipelineType?: string;
    ticketId?: string;
    productId?: string;
  }>();
  
  return <Redirect to={toUrl(params)}/>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [tagged sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). For example:

```js
// Generic functions
// B is the function compose combinator
const B = g => f => x => g (f (x))

const taggedSum = xs => Object.fromEntries (
  xs.map(tag => [tag, value => ({ tag, value })])
)

const cata = matches => ({ tag, value }) => matches[tag] (value)
/////////////////////////

const Kind = taggedSum (['pipeline', 'ticket', 'product', 'local' ])

const path = cata ({
    pipeline: x => `/pipeline/${x}`,
    ticket: x => `/ticket/${x}`,
    product: x => `/product/${x}`,
    local: () => `/pipeline/local`
})

const output1 = B (path) (Kind.pipeline) (1)
const output2 = B (path) (Kind.ticket) (14)
const output3 = B (path) (Kind.product) (3421)
const output4 = B (path) (Kind.local) (0)


console.log ('pipeline:', output1)
console.log ('ticket:', output2)
console.log ('product:', output3)
console.log ('local:', output4)
```