# Categorisation of objects by comparing two objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to categorise the objects by comparing two objects say **data** and **categories**

```
const data = {
  "1a": {
    "name": "1a",
    "count": 154
  },
  "1b": {
    "name": "1b",
    "count": 765
  },
  "1c": {
    "name": "1c",
    "count": 7877
  },
  "777": {
    "name": "777",
    "count": 456
  }
};

const categories = {
    "A_category":["A","1a", "2a"],
    "B_category":["1b", "2b"],
    "C_category":["1c", "2c"],
    "D_category":["1d", "2d"]
};
```

I want to group the data based on the category object, when there is no match the group should be **others** and the resultant data should be like

```
const resultData = [
  { group: 'Others', name: '777', count: 456 },
  { group: 'A_category', name: '1a', count: 154 },
  { group: 'B_category', name: '1b', count: 765 },
  { group: 'C_category', name: '1c', count: 7877 }
]
```

I used the function but not able to achieve the result

```
const resultData = [];
function restructure(data, categories) {
  Object.keys(data).map(
    dataKey => {
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(categories)) {
      value.includes(dataKey) ? resultData.push({"group": key,...data[dataKey]}) : resultData.push({"group": "Others",...data[dataKey]})  ;
      break;
}
    }
  )
}

restructure(data,categories);
```

Comment: Your `data` and `categories` should be arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this as well. Iterate over your `data` entries and find whether the key exists in any of the `categories` object data and push it into the array with found `category` as group or push it with `Others` as group as shown in the below code

```js
const data = {
  "1a": {
    "name": "1a",
    "count": 154
  },
  "1b": {
    "name": "1b",
    "count": 765
  },
  "1c": {
    "name": "1c",
    "count": 7877
  },
  "777": {
    "name": "777",
    "count": 456
  }
};
    
const categories = {
  "A_category": ["A", "1a", "2a"],
  "B_category": ["1b", "2b"],
  "C_category": ["1c", "2c"],
  "D_category": ["1d", "2d"]
};

const resultData = [];

Object.entries(data).map(([key, val])=>{
    let group = Object.keys(categories).find(category=>categories[category].includes(key)) || 'Others'
    resultData.push({
        group,
        ...val
    })

})

console.log(resultData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for` loop you need to use `filter` as `let category = Object.entries(categories).filter(([key, value]) => value.includes(dataKey));`.

If `category.length > 0` then category is available else use `Others`.

Try it below.

```js
const data = {
  "1a": {
    "name": "1a",
    "count": 154
  },
  "1b": {
    "name": "1b",
    "count": 765
  },
  "1c": {
    "name": "1c",
    "count": 7877
  },
  "777": {
    "name": "777",
    "count": 456
  }
};

const categories = {
  "A_category": ["A", "1a", "2a"],
  "B_category": ["1b", "2b"],
  "C_category": ["1c", "2c"],
  "D_category": ["1d", "2d"]
};

const resultData = [];

function restructure(data, categories) {
  Object.keys(data).map(
    dataKey => {
      let category = Object.entries(categories)
        .filter(([key, value]) => value.includes(dataKey));
      resultData.push({
        "group": category.length > 0 ? category[0][0] : "Others",
        ...data[dataKey]
      });
    })
}

restructure(data, categories);
console.log(resultData);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're breaking out of the loop regardless of whether you found the category or not. Your `for` loop will only execute once then breaks immediately. If the first category object matches, it is used, if not `"Others"` is assigned and the loop exits without checking the rest of the categories. Only break out of the loop if the lookup is successful:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(categories)) {
    if(value.includes(dataKey)) {                                  // if this is the category
        resultData.push({ "group": key, ...data[dataKey] });       // use it ...
        return;                                                    // ... and break the loop and the current iteration of forEach. The current object is handled
    }
}

resultData.push({ "group": "Others", ...data[dataKey] });          // if the return statement above is never reached, that means the category was not found, assign "Others"
```

BTW, you can use other array methods to shorten things out like so:

```
function restructure(data, categories) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(key => ({
      "group": Object.keys(categories).find(cat => categories[cat].includes(key)) || "Others",
      ...data[key]
  }));
}
```

Then use like so:

```
const resultData = restructure(data, categories);
```

My method uses `find` to try to find a category key that contains the name of the object, if `find` fails, it returns `null` at which point, the `|| "Others"` part is evaluated and `"Others"` will be used as the group name ([Does JavaScript have "Short-circuit" evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12554578/9867451)).

**Demo:**

```js
const data = {"777":{"name":"777","count":456},"1a":{"name":"1a","count":154},"1b":{"name":"1b","count":765},"1c":{"name":"1c","count":7877}};

const categories = {"A_category":["A","1a","2a"],"B_category":["1b","2b"],"C_category":["1c","2c"],"D_category":["1d","2d"]};

function restructure(data, categories) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(key => ({
      "group": Object.keys(categories).find(cat => categories[cat].includes(key)) || "Others",
      ...data[key]
  }));
}

const resultData = restructure(data, categories);

console.log(resultData);
```