# How does this code work as conditional statements, why aren't there any "if" or "else if" statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the following problem that I need to solve about nested logic, I saw the following possible solution online but I hadn't seen code organized like this and can't help to figure it out. It looks like a different approach I hadn't seen to "if" and "else if" statements, so I would like to understand what's going on. Thank you.

```
let fine = 0;
const [actual, expected] = input.split('\n').map(item => {
  const [day, month, year] = item.split(' ').map(Number);

  return {
    day,
    month,
    year
  };
});

(
  actual.year === expected.year &&
  actual.month === expected.month &&
  actual.day > expected.day
) && (fine = (actual.day - expected.day) * 15);

(
  actual.year === expected.year &&
  actual.month > expected.month
) && (fine = (actual.month - expected.month) * 500);

(actual.year > expected.year) && (fine = 10000);

console.log(fine);
}
```

Comment: Terrible abuse of the **short-circuiting behavior** of logical operators: `false && never_called()`

Comment: Related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12554578/2864740 // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND // https://dev.to/akhil_001/short-circuit-evaluation-in-javascript-3o5a

Comment: Very poorly written code.  It appears to be "obtuse on purpose" which is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code takes advantage of something called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which isn't unique to JavaScript. In a broad sense, short-circuit evaluation means only evaluating a boolean expression if it is necessary to determine the ultimate outcome. It also takes advantage of the fact that in JS, assignment operators act as expressions.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```js
let x;
console.log(x = 2) // 2
```

What this means is that you can have an assignment expression at the end of a list of conditions to act as an if statement. Due to short circuit evaluation, the assignment expression will only be evaluated if the ultimate true/false value of the full expression is not predetermined by the conditions.

```js
let x;
(false && x = 1) // does nothing, false && ___ = false
(true || x = 2) // does nothing, true || ___ = true
(true && x = 3) // sets x = 3, true && ___ evaluates ___
(false || x = 4) // sets x = 4, false || ___ evaluates ___
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has [short-circuit boolean evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and the code in your question uses that extensively.

Take for example:

```
a() && b(); // if (a()) b();
```

Because both `a()` and `b()` need to evaluate to a *truthy* value for the entire statement to be considered true, JavaScript will not evaluate `b()` if `a()` already evaluates to a *falsy* value.

Similarly:

```
c() || d(); // if (!c()) d();
```

Because only one of `c()` or `d()` needs to evaluate to a *truthy* value for the entire statement to be considered true, JavaScript will not evaluate `d()` if `c()` already evaluates to a *truthy* value.

This can be used to implement logical branching, much like an if-else structure, although in most cases it does adversely impact the code's readability.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing big changes in your code.

Heare simple syntax with the conditional operation in javascript `var varname = condition ? true part code : false part code`.

```
let fine = 0;
    const [actual, expected] = input.split('\n').map(item => {
        const [day, month, year] = item.split(' ').map(Number);

        return { day, month, year };
    });

    fine = (actual.year === expected.year && actual.month === expected.month && actual.day > expected.day) ? ((actual.day - expected.day) * 15) : 0;

    fine = (actual.year === expected.year && actual.month > expected.month) ? ((actual.month - expected.month) * 500) : 0;

    fine = (actual.year > expected.year) ? 10000 : 0;

    console.log(fine);
```

[Something more](https://one7techlab.com)