# How do I create a third object from two objects using the key values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, object

Object 1:

```
{positive: ['happy', 'excited', 'joyful'], negative: ['depressed', 'sad', 'unhappy']}
```

Object 2:

```
{happy: 6, excited: 1, unhappy: 3}
```

What I want -
Result:

```
{positive: 7, negative: 3}
```

How do I achieve this?

I have used the following to get the category object 2 falls into but I'm not sure how to dynamically create the third object as the size of these objects grow. **I cannot use for...of or for...in due to eslint airbnb rules**

```
    function getKeyByValue(value) {
        return Object.keys(object).find((key) => object[key] === value);
    }
```

Comment: Start with looping.

Comment: Is this a homework? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried getting key by value to find the category object two belongs to but I’m wondering how to create a third object dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to create the new object. For each entry, [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as `[key, feelings]`, we calculate the sum using a nested `reduce`: for each `feeling` in `feelings`, we use the value from `object2`, if exists, or `0` otherwise using [short circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12554578/9867451) (`object2[feeling] || 0`), like so:

```
let result = Object.entries(object1).reduce((result, [key, feelings]) => {
  result[key] = feelings.reduce((sum, feeling) => sum + (object2[feeling] || 0), 0);
  return result;
}, {});
```

**Demo:**

```js
let object1 = { positive: ["happy", "excited", "joyful"], negative: ["depressed", "sad", "unhappy"] };
let object2 = { happy: 6, excited: 1, unhappy: 3 };


let result = Object.entries(object1).reduce((result, [key, feelings]) => {
  result[key] = feelings.reduce((sum, feeling) => sum + (object2[feeling] || 0), 0);
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
    obj1 = {positive: ['happy', 'excited', 'joyful'], negative: ['depressed', 'sad', 'unhappy']}
    obj2 = {happy: 6, excited: 1, unhappy: 3}
    
    const result ={}
    
    for (let key of Object.keys(obj1)) {
        result[key] = obj1[key].reduce(
            (acc, value) => { return acc + (obj2[value] || 0) }, 0)
    }
    
    console.log(result)
```

Notes:

1. `for ... of Object.keys()` is more preferable in most situations than `for ... in` because `for ... in` iterate not only over the object's own keys, but also over its prototype chains.
2. Instead Object.keys() you can also use [Reflect.ownKeys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys)

Comment: I have tried something like this but airbnb eslint is complaining due to for of/for in loops so I'm trying to figure out different approaches