# Do operators work this way in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've heard about something called operator evaluation. Now I'm asking you to tell me if I'm right:

So take a look at the following code

```
var a = 5;
false && (a = 2);
console.log(a);
```

the result in this code will remain 5
that's because the `&&` operator will look first at the first operand and after that it will look at the second operand. and because the first operand is false we wont get to the second operand so it wont get executed.

This thing called an operator evaluation and this operator evaluation applied to any operator. it first look at the first operand(first meaning the one on the left side) and after that the second(right side)

Am I right ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript have "Short-circuit" evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#assignment_operators

Comment: "*this thing called an operator evaluation*" - not really

Comment: @MisterJojo what do you mean? I just tried it out and works as expected.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "short-circuit evaluation".

Comment: @Camilo I do a lot of TPM. If this kind of code actually passes to the interpreter, this syntax hijacking should be avoided. Its ambiguity turns into a nightmare for those who will have to maintain and develop this kind of code, Programmers end up building complex conditions in part one, then they do the same on part two.