# How to repeat the same short code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, dry

```
   if (
     titleValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
     sepiValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
     discValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
     dateValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
   ) {
     movieCard[i].style.display = "";
   } else {
     movieCard[i].style.display = "none";
   }
```

** I want to short this code at code statement `||`**

I want to use dry consent in this code, please anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code review questions do not fit SO. For code review requests use [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you think about:

```
const hasFilter = [titleValue, sepiValue, discValue, dateValue]
  .find(item => item.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1);

movieCard[i].style.display = hasFilter ? "" : "none";
```