# What does the second line of the code mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

please what does the second line of the following code mean, is it a tenary operation, if it's not then what is it and what does it mean

```
   const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
   !user && res.status(404).json("user not found");
```

Comment: The ternary operator is `?` followed by `:`. `&&` is the [AND logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#logical_operators). This is just a "witty" one-liner that makes use of [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation).

Comment: It's an (in my opinion) ugly way to write the equivalent of `if (!user) res.status.....`

Answer (score 4):

It is not a ternary operator.
The `&&` operator is evaluating the left part, after coercing it to boolean if it is not.
Then, if it turns `true`, it evaluates the right part after `&&` and return the resulting value.
But if it turns false, it returns the left part (not coerced).

The `!` operator do two things : it coerces into boolean and returns the opposite value.

So here, if there is a `user` found in the first line, `!user` will be `false` and `res.status(404).json("user not found")` will not be evaluated.

If on the contrary no `user` was found, `!user` will be `true` and the second line will return a status 404.