# Why does swapping element order with regex OR operator "|" matter?

Tags: regex

I have some text with lowercase letters, dots, parentheses, and greater than and less than signs. Suppose that I want to match substrings on each line that (1) begin with a period, (2) contain any number of letters, and (3) have a non-negative number of either parentheses or `<`/`>` signs, but *not both*. Therefore, given this text,

```
foobar.hello(world)
foobar.hello<world>
foobar.hello>>>world<>(baz)
```

I want to match `.hello(world)` on the first line, `.hello<world>` on the second line, and `.hello>>>world<>` on the third (since I can't mix parentheses and `<`/`>` signs).

I could use two regular expressions to match my desired strings, `\.[a-z()]+` and `\.[a-z<>]+`. However, because regexes are more efficient when similar patterns are combined, I tried to combine them into a single regex with a logical OR `|`:

```
\.(?:[a-z()]+|[a-z<>]+)
```

[After trying this online](https://regex101.com/), while the regex matched my desired substring for the first line, for the second and third lines, it only matched `.hello`. Yet when I switch the order of the elements, the opposite happens—the first line gets matched as `.hello`, and the second and third lines are matched as desired. This comes to me as a surprise, since I wouldn't think order would matter with an OR operator. What's happening here?

Comment: In fact, order does matter, even in programming languages. This behaviour is called [short-circuitry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56057305).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex OR operator terminates after the first successful match. This is the short circuiting behavior described by InSync's comment. To make this more obvious, if our regular expression is `a+|a+b+|a+b+c+`, then no matter the string, our regex can only return matches containing the letter `a`:

```py
String                         Matches
--------------------           --------------------
'a'                            ['a']
'aaa'                          ['aaa']
'aaabbb'                       ['aaa']
'aaabbbccc'                    ['aaa']
'yabba dabba doo'              ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Therefore, the regex that solves the original problem is

```
\.[a-z]*(?:[a-z()]+|[a-z<>]+)
```

This correctly matches `.hello(world)`, `.hello<world>`, and `.hello>>>world<>` in the three test cases in the original question.

When I asked the question, I had naively believed that because regular expressions are greedy, they must return the longest possible match from any string. This is not so. The greedy property of a regular expression only means that a quantifier such as `+` or `*` will continue to match, so long as more characters are available. However, this is not the same thing as a regex backtracking to find all valid matches, then comparing their relative lengths. In terms of finite-state automata, if it were possible to count and compare lengths, then the *a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>* language would be regular, which is a contradiction. Moreover, although regular languages are closed under a finite number of union operations, I was essentially trying to "glue" together individual automata to get the automaton of the union, like gluing together the `a+`, `a+|b+`, and `a+b+c+` languages to obtain `a+|a+b+|a+b+c+`, even though the correct regex for the union of these languages is `a+(b+(c+)?)?`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `[a-z()]+` does not require brackets in the input, so it matches `hello`. Further, alternations match left-to-right, so `.hello` is successfully matched and the engine stops there when the input has angled brackets.

To fix the problem, *require* brackets (that agree with each other) via an alternation for the brackets and their contents, placed *after* the initial part, so:

```
\.[a-z]+(?:\([a-z]+\)|<[a-z]+>)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/tdcV5hte7B2663).

This approach has the (possible) advantage of being more strict; your regex would match everything from dot onwards of

```
foobar.()()()(((((()foo
```

which is probably not wanted (although the input may not have syntactically invalid content).

Comment: To be honest, I actually intended for the regex to match monstrosities with unpaired delimiters like `foobar.()()()(((((()foo`, at least in theory, anyways; my real use cases aren’t so horrendous. I think my example gave the wrong impression, and I’ve edited my question accordingly. I’m more interested in an explanation than a fix, so this was helpful anyways (+1)