# Why is a TypeError exception guarded against with the && operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typeerror, logical-operators

Suppose I have a variable `x` declared as: `var x`. Now when I try to access a property named `value` of `x` then I get a type error because `value` doesn't exist. Now if I run `x.value` as it is in the console I will get a clear type error exception. But If I use `undefined && x.value` I get no type error; `undefined` is returned. So I infer that `undefined && non-existing` returns `undefined`. On the same lines I suppose anything like `undefined && random786` should also return undefined. But it gives a type error. So,

> Why does `undefined && random786` -- where random786 is not declared anywhere -- give a type error while `undefined && x.value` doesn't give any type error?

Comment: But `undefined && random786;` does *not* result in a TypeError.

Comment: Short circuit evaluation, if expression can be evaluated on the first operand only, the second is ignored. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049006/using-s-short-circuiting-as-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the expression on the left side of `&&` evaluates to `undefined` (or `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, or `false`), then the right side is not evaluated at all. Neither `random786`, where that's not declared, nor `x.value` where "value" is not a property of the object, will cause an error.

For object properties, a *reference* to a property that does not exist will not result in an error. Thus:

```
if (x.someProperty)
```

will not throw an exception so long as the value of `x` is an object. You start running into problems if your code assumes that "someProperty" *does* exist and that it's something like a function reference:

```
x.someProperty();
```

That *will* throw an exception when there's no "someProperty" (or if it isn't a function), and thus the fairly common idiom

```
x.someProperty && x.someProperty();
```

Comment: Yes, try these two lines: `true && (console.log('hello'))` and `undefined && (console.log('goodbye'))`, you'll see that the instruction to output `goodbye` is never executed.