# Different styles of condition in PHP

Tags: php

I want to know if there is anything different at the action level for these codes.

```
if ($settings->someBoleanValue) {
    $this->doStuff();
}
```

and this:

```
$settings->someBoleanValue && $this->doStuff();
```

Which one is better? and why

Comment: The question of "which is better" is opinion-based, so doesn't meet the rules for what questions the site accepts listed in the [help/on-topic]. The question of "is there anything different" is quite vague, but basically amounts to "no, those two examples will do the same thing".

Comment: I don't know if there's anything different on a processing level, but I know the first one is more readable.

Comment: It'd not all about being functionally the same, it's also about the sanity of the people who have to maintain the code you write. Why write the second version as opposed to the first?

Comment: @NigelRen It's kind of the shorthanded version of the first one, isn't it?

Comment: @IMSoP It's not an opinion-based question; I'm seeking the differences in the process level.

Comment: So is `$s->b && $this->q();` but does it mean anything?

Comment: You already had an answer by IMSoP: _"those two examples will do the same thing"_.

Comment: @NigelRen Your example is not standard, as it used unrecognizable names for properties and methods. Using shorthand is totally different from that. This is an example of shorthand: Instead of using `$name = $name ?? 'mark';` in a function, you can use the shorthanded version: `$name ??= 'mark';`

Comment: What does `differences in the process level` mean exactly? Are you asking if they will behave differently / produce different output? Or what?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware So they are the same even at the process level? when being compiled and...?

Comment: You'd need someone who knows the PHP byte-code compiler and interpreter in-depth probably, to understand if the different syntax results in any different output at that level, or any optimisations etc. There might be people on here who can definitively answer that, but unfortunately probably there are very few of them. But if that's your question, you should ask that question specifically and clearly, not the vague, ambiguous question you originally posted (which is why your question is closed). P.S. Little bit of background on PHP runtime mechanics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1514737/5947043

Comment: Ah, here it becomes clear that you didn't define what you mean by "action level" and "process level". You still leave it open to us to guess what you mean.... In general users of PHP are not interested in what happens on the machine language level, we do care about things like execution time. That you can test yourself, but I think you'll not be able to find a difference.

Comment: @NigelRen *"Why write the second version as opposed to the first?"* That style is more common in some languages like JS (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049006/using-s-short-circuiting-as-an-if-statement)).

Comment: @Olivier, may be, but does that make it any better or applicable to PHP?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got my answer. It sounds like they are the same at the lowest level that a PHP user cares.

Comment: @MiaadP I specifically said **the part of your question about which is better** is opinion-based, because without a more specific qualifier "better" is a matter of opinion. The other half of your question is not opinion-based, but is still hard to answer, because "the action level" is not a standard term, so it's unclear what kinds of differences you'd be interested in. At some stage in processing, they will be different, because they're different source code; at some other stage, they *might* be optimised to be identical. That optimisation might also depend on settings - OpCache, JIT, etc